# How to get List of Edges for particular node in cytoscape js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to trace edges of selected nodes and then display them on a graph using `cy.add()` exactly on the same position

I try to retrieve edges using `.connectedEdges()`. but it gives me this

```
u {length: 0, _private: {…}}
```

Now I don't know how to trace the ID's of edges to display them again on a graph using `cy.add()`

Is there something is missing...

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are calling connectedEdges() please? :)

Comment: cy.$('#'+ele.data('id')).connectedEdges()

Comment: I don't know if cy.$(...) returns a collection or not, I edited my answer with the method that definetely does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the outgoing edges via the outgoers() function, where you also get the targets of the edges you search for:

```
var outgoers = collection.outgoers();          // This contains all connected edges and their targets
var targets = collection.outgoers().targets(); // This contains all targets of your selected node
cy.ready(function () {
   for (node in outgoers) { 
      // Do what you like here
   }
});
```

It is better to use:

```
cy.nodes("[id = '" + id + "']").connectedEdges();
```

Comment: if i use this will it work...
cy.add(cy.nodes("[id = '" + id + "']").connectedEdges())

Comment: Well you can save all the x and y coordinates of your collection and then add the nodes and edges to the graph according to that, just try the cy.add() and tell me what happened :)

Comment: right on ! , perfect solution for my problem, I needed to filter and display only specific nodes and their edges based on a condition.